# What should the name of our main chatroom be?

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Stack Exchange site (Not all) main chatroom has a unique name that is related to the main site itself.

For example:

- Super User: Root Access
- Gaming: The Bridge
- IoT: Chat of Things
- Unix & Linux: /dev/chat

and etc

What should our main chat room be named?

[The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/311917)

> 5. Whats an interesting name for the chat room?
>    Every site comes with its official chat room. This is created automatically and can be reached from the Site Switcher on the top left. The chat room is the third place of your community, after main and meta. It is like the lounge where everybody can get together to discuss, complain and have fun. Personalizing this space to reflect your community and what you are, is one of the small steps to take towards building an active and engaged community.
>    Try to get a few ideas up, discuss and vote on them. The name could be something esoteric in your field, or something that every person may understand. Whichever it may be, go ahead and start the discussion!

Answer (score 20):

## The Garbage Collector

Nice and snappy. Originally suggested by me [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/140719?m=62399157#62399157).

Comment: Then the off-topic room can be The Garbage Disposal

Comment: @Adám I think name is more appropriate for an equivalent to the Bakery.

Comment: Off topic room can be the Reference Counter

Comment: The thing I don't like about this name is that it suggests that what we post in chat is worthless noise (garbage). Hopefully that's not *always* the case... :)

Answer (score 3):

The Token Stream

<sup>(related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)</sup>

Comment: The Lexical Scope

Answer (score 2):

### The REPL

On the grounds that read-eval-print loop feels like a chat.

Comment: interesting, but feels a little off, since a REPL is usually a "one on one conversation"

Answer (score -2):

My personal favourite:

### The YACC

A perfectly descriptive pun.

Comment: It's better to split up different ideas into different answers, that way users can vote exactly on idea they agree with and ones they don't.

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't want to spam the group with 8 silly suggestions and 2 semi-serious ones. I think "The YACC" may be the best pun.

Comment: OK, I'll edit into two suggestions.

Answer (score -4):

## The Debugger

Answer (score -4):

## The Operating Theatre

Languages can go into the operating theatre to be fixed.

Answer (score -8):

**Words and Languages**. Words being what is in the chat, programming languages being the site topic